# Dotenv not loaded when deploying Bedrock-Capistrano

Tags: php, wordpress, capistrano

I'm doing my first Bedrock *multisite* install using bedrock-capistrano.

Everything works locally, however once deployed, I get

`Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in <snip>/releases/<snip>/public/wp/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1474`

Obviously I did set this info in my .env file, and `nobody` with no password isn't the information I set ;) . I have checked that the env file is properly located; and it is. I have no other logs or error shown. Somehow it feels like it's not accessing the info properly.

Any ideas why could the dotenv not work?

Comment: I added check to see if dotenv loads
`if (class_exists('Dotenv')) ` - the answer is no. Gives me a good hint...

Comment: Turns out the capistrano deployment script did not run `composer install` as expected thus it wasn't loaded. Did it manually and it appears to have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*bedrock-capistrano*, which was supposed to run `composer install` as part of the deployment, did not do it as expected.

Connecting to the server over SSH and running `composer install` manually did the trick to get dotenv to work.

(Now the issue is "why did composer not work", but that's something else entirely)